# Mysql groupby date count from specific time range

Tags: mysql

I am able to groupby date and get total count for each date using following query:

```
SELECT
  DATE(work_time)    as dt,
  dayname(work_time) as dayofweek,
  COUNT(*)           as deploy_count
FROM table_1
where 
  work_type = 'deploy'
GROUP BY 
  DATE(work_time);
```

What I want to do is instead the whole number of deploys I want total of deployes within 00:00:00 ~ 06:00:00 time interval for each day.

This is my approach:

```
SELECT
  DATE(work_time)    as dt,
  dayname(work_time) as dayofweek,
  COUNT(*)           as deploy_count
FROM table_1
where 
  work_type = 'deploy' and
  (cast(work_time as time) between '00:00:00' and '06:00:00')
GROUP BY 
  DATE(work_time);
```

however deploy_count in second query is larger than the first which definitely doesn't make sense since first is counting total deploy in a day and second query is count total deploy in a day within 0~6am.

EDIT:

Actually this works... but since it ignores 0 counts I've got confused.

I am going to leave it up since I didn't find question similar to this therefore other people might benefit from my solution.

I am happy to close it once duplicate question has been found. Thanks!

Comment: write an expression that takes a workdate and reduces this to the same number for the 6 hr interval. like GROUP BY [TO_SECONDS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds)(work_time) DIV (60*60*6)

Comment: yes your query actually works. 0 wasn't actually ignored, the row for the criteria didn't exist.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query